# Generalization of OpenCV medianBlur?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

In OpenCV, medianBlur replaces each pixel with dstPixel so that 50% of the aperture pixel is brighter than dstPixel.

Is there a function to replace each pixel with dstPixel so that X% of the pixels are brighter than dstPixel for a given X?

Comment: That’s called a percentile filter. Not sure if OpenCV has one, but DIPlib [does](https://diplib.github.io/diplib-docs/group__nonlinear.html#gaa9da8740a9942de5ba9ad00d3a6905ff).